# Optional function arguments

Tags: r

I am looking at the `traincontrol()` function in R.

when you use the help function (`?traincontrol`), how can you tell which arguments are optional/have a default value?

Comment: If it has a default value, it is optional. If it says it is optional, it is optional. Otherwise, you must assume it is mandatory.

Comment: You can tell if an argument has a default value by seeing if there is an `=`. For instance, `lm(..., data, ...)` has no default value, so does not appear optional by that formal definition, but the help page says this is *"an optional data frame"*. `lm(..., model=TRUE,...)` has a default value of `TRUE`, so if you do nothing it will be "true". `lm(formula, ...)` has no `=`, and does not mention `optional` in the description, so you should assume it is mandatory.

Comment: If you look at the `Usage` part of the documentation (`help("trainControl")`) you can see a call of the function with all its arguments. The values shown in the `Usage` part are the arguments default value. If an argument has no default value it has to be defined. Every argument that has a default value does not have to be defined by you. You can check if an argument is optional in the `Arguments` section. For example in `trainControl` the argument `indexFinal` is an optional vector.